# Using the rest api on grails applicatoin and printing response in gsp page

Tags: grails

hi friends i am working on  grails using the web services i.e rest api is developed using the java and these are my request and response

```
 requestBody: 
 {"color": "Select Color", "size": "Select Size", "fullName": "hg", "address": "g", "shape": "Select Shape", "finish": "Select Finish", "fileUpload": "new file","description": "gh", "telephone_Number": "9900887766", "email_Address": "email_Address", "line1": "ssap newas", "city": "gfdg", "state": "gf", "zip": "null", "ship_address": "g", "ship_line1": "abc xyz", "ship_city": "", "ship_state": "",   "ship_zip": "null"};

 response :
 {"statusCode":"1","referenceNumber":"5","errorCode":null}
```

now i want the response status code should be printed on .gsp page

Answer (score 0):

With JSON you need to do it via javascript, use jQuery to update that html element that would contain the status text. Such things are very easy to do with angularjs though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use JsonSlurper to convert json to map

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"statusCode":"1","referenceNumber":"5","errorCode":null}`)

assert result.statusCode == "1"
```